# Remove Class Used as Target

Tags: jquery

Given this bit of JS:

```
$('.list-group > a').click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 32
    }, 'slow');

    $(this).addClass('active-tab');
    $('.glyphicon',this).removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
});


$(".active-tab").click( function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active-tab');
    $('.glyphicon',this).removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
});
```

On the first click, I add the `active-tab` class, but I'd like this class to be removed if someone was to click on that anchor if active (like a standard toggle). The issue is that the `active-tab` class is not being removed. Thoughts?

Comment: It's not clear what you want

Comment: Could you toss some `HTML` our way? Oh, and `CSS` would be lovely too... Maybe even a [JS Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'd like this class to be removed if someone was to click on that anchor if active (like a standard toggle*

**Its a wild guess. If I understood correctly**

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Ideally you should replace `document` with closest static container.

Example

```
$(document).on('click', '.active-tab', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('active-tab');
    $('.glyphicon',this).removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
});
```

Comment: @jonasll, Glad I could help. I was not sure though